# Python web-server not responding to CORS request

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, cors

I think the `CORS` headers have been all set up correctly. The server starts but trying with Postman or with my React web app to send a `POST` request, the server does not respond, nor does it prints the `POST` parameters. If I cancel the `POST` request from Postman, it prints the parameters and the request details.

I spent some hours trying to find a working example in Python 3 to build a `CORS` API server (`CORS` seems to be needed by Google Chrome when testing the web app), but I didn't succeed.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import json

class CORSRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200, "ok")
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                         self.headers['origin'])
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):

        parameters = json.load(self.rfile)
        print(parameters)

        body = bytes(json.dumps({'trial': 'blablalbla'}), 'utf-8')

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(body)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9000), CORSRequestHandler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

I send the request body as JSON, both from Postman and the React app. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like a pretty basic problem. Do the parameters print when you do the POST? Have you tried a normal (non-CORS) httprequesthandler and got that working? Tried a GET?

Comment: The parameters are printed by `print(parameters)` only when I cancel the request from Postman or reload the web app in Chrome. The non-CORS httprequesthandler worked well until I needed CORS because of Google Chrome.

Comment: At the moment I solved using Bottle, but a solution may be usefull for others...